# How to replace NULL with Unknown from MediaItem in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mpmediaitem

When i retrieve Media Info like `Artist` , `Album` , Song Title from `MPMediaItem` in iOS, However some songs doesn't have Artist Name and Album.

So i got return value with NULL

Here is my codes

```
MPMediaItem *currentItem = self.player.nowPlayingItem;

    NSString *Artist = [currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
    NSString *Title = [currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    NSString *Album = [currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
```

If song doesn't have Artist and Album name , it's return `NULL` Value.

I want to replace that `NULL` value with `Unknown` value.

How can i replace it?

Thanks for your reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be elegant, you can add a category to `MPMediaItem` like this:

```
@implementation MPMediaItem (Readable)

- (id)readableValueForProperty:(NSString *)prop
{
    id originalValue = [self valueForProperty:prop];

    if (originalValue == nil) {
        return @"Unknown";
    }

    return originalValue;
}

@end
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
NSString *artist = [currentItem readableValueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
```

Note that this is dangerous if you're getting a property that isn't an `NSString` originally. If you're operating with string values only, this should be fine, though.

An approach which is always safe but less readable (and more redundant) would be checking each and every returned value by hand:

```
NSString *artist = [currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
if (artist == nil) artist = @"Unknown";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSString*)getValueFromMediaItem:(MPMediaItem*)item forKey:(NSUInteger)key
{
    NSString * value = [item valueForProperty:key];

   if([value isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || !value)
      return @"Unknown";

    return value;
}

//call this by:
    NSString *Artist = [self getValueFromMediaItem:currentItem forKey: MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
```

Comment: I don't think `[NSNull null]` is returned upon encountering a nonexistent property, it's rather `nil` or `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (strArtist==nil)
        {
            NSString *emptystring=@" ";
            [ArrayArtist addObject:emptystring];
        }
        else
        {
            [ArrayArtist addObject:strArtist];

        }
```